# How to interact with a webpage with python?

Tags: python

Basically, I want to be able to mimic the functions of an internet browser, but without having to actually graphically render it. My ideal scenario would be, for example, a script which opens a connection with a webpage, makes all the necessary calls and interactions, and can list what javascript went off (this is a trivial example, but is the sort of thing I'm looking for). I basically want to be able to "browse" from python while logging various events that happen. The real dream would be able to program in reactions (such as sending a click if there's a box that looks like this or that, for example).

Is there a nice way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).

Answer (score 3):

You should check out [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/). It works on the command line but also has a [python api](http://twill.idyll.org/python-api.html).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/). You script it in JavaScript rather than Python, but it seems to be a nice headless browser based on WebKit.

Another option might be to use Selenium, which has a Python binding available for it too: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium